# Converting a factor to numeric variable gives an error while using if statement after using as.numeric in R

Tags: r, numeric, categorical-data

I have an age column in my dataset. It is factor with many levels.

[image: An example is shown in the picture]

I'm trying to rearrange the column values to be grouped as "20 and under", "20 to 29", "30 to 39" and "40 to 49"

I try doing the following:

```
data$age_groups <- data$age

for (i in length(data$age_groups)) {
  if (data$age_groups[i] == '16 and under' |
      as.numeric(as.character(data$age_groups[i])) <= 20) {
    data$age_groups[i] <- '20 and under'
  }
}
```

By running this block , I only get a message stating invalid factor level, NA generated.
Also this hasn't altered anything in the age_groups column. Can someone guide me through this?

Comment: Probably has issues converting character to numeric when there is more than just a number.

Comment: Work on the factor levels: `levels(data$age_groups)[levels(data$age_groups) == '16 and under' |
      (is.finite(as.numeric(levels(data$age_groups)))  & as.numeric(levels(data$age_groups)) <= 20 )] <- '20 and under'` (not tested vecause you don't provide example input)

Comment: @Roland. Thanks for the comment. The part where (is.finite(as.numeric(levels(data$age_groups))) isn't clear. Could you please explain it?

Comment: @user2974951 Thanks for the comment. Yes that is an issue which I need help with

Comment: `is.finite` tests if something is a finite number (i.e., not `NA`, `NaN` or `Inf`).

Comment: @Roland I tried your solution however it gives a warning NAs introduced by coercion. I have checked using str(), summary() and is.na() on the result. It doesn't have any NA values but still it shows the warning.

Comment: Of course it shows the warnings. These come from the `as.numeric` part, because it also converts text that's not numbers.

Comment: Can we avoid the warning, or is it safe to ignore it?

Answer (score 0):

See https://forcats.tidyverse.org/reference/fct_recode.html

```
x <- factor(c("16 and under", "17", "18", "20", "22", "26",  "29",  "30-39", "40-49"))
y = fct_recode(x, "20 and under" = "16 and under", "20 and under" = "17", 
       "20 and under" = "18", "20 to 29" = "20", "20 to 29" = "22", 
       "20 to 29" = "26", "20 to 29"="29")

y
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It is easy to do this however if you have a lot of values in age that you need to put in a range, the code gets very lengthy and repetitive. I have shown only a few values in my question but I have a lot more in my actual dataset.

Comment: OK. So assuming you have values for all ages, and need to group them in decades, you can try with the following, which is going to be about 10 lines, I guess: 

```df<-  data.frame(age = c("16 and under", "17", "18", "20", "22", "26",  "29",  "30-39", "40-49"))

df <- df %>% mutate(age_group =  case_when(
  str_detect(age, "^2") ~ "20 to 29",
  TRUE ~ as.character(age)
))```